# When importing an SVG file, there is no color

Tags: svg

I have a question about importing SVG files to blender. I am a beginner and I've been watching this tutorial, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zthvZvw-yJE. And when he imports his SVG file into blender it is in color. When I try to import my SVG file it shows up black. Can you help me solve this problem.

I use Boxy SVG editor and Inkscape. I've tried both and it still is black in blender.

Thanks

Comment: what Blender version are you using? I think colors didn't work before 2.8 or 2.9

Comment: blender version 2.93.1

Comment: https://www.blendernation.com/2019/07/16/daily-blender-tip-318-import-svg-files-with-colors/ try this method...it helped me

Answer (score 1):

Change the colour mode from CMYK to RGB when exporting from Illustrator. This can be done under *File > Document Color Mode> RGB Color*.

Comment: The OP is asking for Inkscape and Boxy SVG editor, not Illustrator