# Unable to view colored SVG image

Tags: mesh, image, svg

Using Adobe Illustrator we created .svg from png file.

Now we imported svg in blender and converted all vectors into meshes using
Object->convert ->Mesh

the output is as shown below

We are unable to view colored svg image, pls suggest the way forward

[svg file used](https://fashion-desings.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/common/casuals/tshirts/userchoice/groverhouse3.svg)

[image]
Thanks
vijay

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/234286/when-importing-an-svg-file-there-is-no-color

Comment: @john Eason the option of setting color mode from CMYK to RGB  is already inplace.

Comment: No idea in that case. I've never used Illustrator.

Comment: When exporting from Illustrator ensure Advanced Options > CSS Properties are set to **Presentation Attributes**

Answer (score 6):

When exporting from *Illustrator* ensure *Advanced Options > CSS Properties* are set to **Presentation Attributes**

[image]

## Issues

... but you will deal with much bigger problem - "holes" in segments. This is partly because of blender's issue (for years) to handle right points on the same Z axis (I guess) ... partly because of bad topology (double points or screwed path). I don't know about any better solution than take care manually piece by piece to check the problematic place.

[image]

Another issue is overlapping parts that seems to be an another issue called Z-fight ... since blender reads all these elements at the same level there is not clear what to render bellow and what is above ... so you can expect artefacts in render (or even visible in viewport) or already hidden parts of railing.

## Tip

I don't know what is your goal, but to avoid all these issues consider to **[Import SVG as Grease Pencil](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.3/files/import_export/grease_pencil_svg.html)** object that supports layers.

Comment: Thanks @vkidu ur point fixed the issue https://i.stack.imgur.com/121Qe.png

Comment: If the answer is correct, mark it as such   ;)  @ 
user1577494